# Regions Between Curves(applications of integration)

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area of the region bounded by $y=x, y=1/x, y=0$, and $x=2$.

Comment: A plain, uninteresting textbook exercise?  Really?

Comment: @B.Goddard How would you like me to spice that up for you?

Comment: Crawl out from under your trilby, and bring it on.  You posted here either not reading or not caring about the rules.  If "spice" means context, then yes, let's have some.  What did you try?  Where did the problem come from?  We don't exist here to just grind out homework problems for lazy ne'er-do-wells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{Area} = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 xdx + \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 \dfrac{1}{x}dx$$.

Can you work out the details ?

Comment: Yes! thank you very much! for whatever reason when I was doing my math I wrote y=x as a straight horizontal line